# How to change url from javascript with Polymer?

Tags: routes, polymer-1.0

I can switch pages from Javascript with the help of iron-pages normally but it doesn't change the browser's URL path so when the user refreshes, he then is redirected back to the previous page. I'm sure a simple example or idea would help a lot.

Comment: You might want to look into using a router. Unsurprisingly, there is [an element for that!](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route). There is a good video on how to use it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRONodYEF2A&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN&index=2) (note that in that video it is called `carbon-route` as the video is slightly out of date although the API should be unchanged).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I really appreciate it but it still doesn't tell anything about changing the url's route using only javascript like window.location. I have achieved pretty much everything what the video told but I need to reroute based on a rule I created via javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having the `app-route` component

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
```

You can change the route from JS simply setting the route's path

```
this.set('route.path', '/foo');
```